# Not able to re-populate back vue2-daterange picker value

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue2-daterange-picker

Hi i do have existing values to be populated back for datarange picker

for single daterange picker it is working for multi it is not working

here is what i have tried

**Question:** range is not working and even format `DD-MM-YYYY` is not working

```js
Vue.use(DatePicker.default); // don't worry about this, it's just for the demo
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
   data () {
    return {
      date1:['10-07-2021'],
      date2:['10-07-2021','18-07-2021'],
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue2-datepicker@1.9.7/dist/build.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>

<div id="app">
 <date-picker v-model="date1" lang="en" format="DD-MM-YYYY"></date-picker>
  <date-picker v-model="date2" :range="Boolean(true)" format="DD-MM-YYYY" lang="en" ></date-picker>
</div>
```

Please help me thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The date picker takes standard javascript Date format. So the date has to be converted to a compatible format first e.g. YYYY-MM-DD or MM/DD/YYYY. For more information, you can refer to https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_date_formats.asp

```js
Vue.use(DatePicker.default); // don't worry about this, it's just for the demo
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      date1: ['07-10-2021'],
      date2: ['07-10-2021', '07-18-2021']
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue2-datepicker@1.9.7/dist/build.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <date-picker v-model="date1" lang="en" format="DD-MM-YYYY"></date-picker>
  <date-picker v-model="date2" :range="Boolean(true)" format="DD-MM-YYYY" lang="en"></date-picker>
</div>
```

Comment: even for single we can use Date object?

Comment: you answers works but still `format` problem is there for date1 `7` is the month not date `10-07-2021` . expected in the format `DD-MM-YYYY`

Comment: and for date2 `08` is now where there.  from where it is coming we don't know  `new Date(2021, 7, 10), new Date(2021, 7, 18)`

Comment: Seems like I overlooked the main issue here which is the supported date format. I have edited the answer for your reference.

Comment: date object one worked for me, so i'm accepting your solution thanks !!